# Angular EventListener for mousemove event only fires on CLICK, but not on MOVE

Tags: angular, mousemove

Whenever I move the mouse over my website, I want to log out the current cursor position.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7mhean?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Try running the website and then click in the screen, it will produce a log. But not when you just move the mouse.

this is how I start listening to the mouse move:

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event']) documentClickEvent($event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log('Through HostListener - MouseMove Event Details: ', $event)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just tried it in the Firefox Browser, there it works. It seems to be only a problem with my Chrome and Brave Browser. Maybe the console settings are not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stackblitz that you linked shows this:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) documentClickEvent($event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('Through HostListener - Click Event Details: ', $event)
}
```

The `HostListener` is listening to click events, so your logging will only be triggered by clicking on the screen.

I copied the code snippet you have in your post (so that `HostListener` is listening to `document:mousemove`), and that triggered the logging on moving the mouse as expected.